# Understanding Magento's unsetChild method

Tags: magento

I would like to understand the Magento Blocks, and therefore I read a Magento 1.5 code of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract .

The insert($block,,,$alias) method
first calls the setChild($alias,$block) method, which builds a _children array (value=$block, key=$alias),
and after that builds a _sortedChildren array (value=$name, key=number).

What I cannot understand is that the unsetChild($alias) method, after unsetting the _children[$alias] item… tries to find the corresponding _sortedChildren item via array_search($alias,_sortedChildren)… well, the values of _sortedChildren are block names, not aliases !

Does unsetChild work with a child whose alias is unequal to its name ?

Comment: Probably it is a bug, maybe it is fixed in more new versions?

Comment: Maybe... Can someone check a newer version ?

Comment: If it is a bug, I think that it lies in the insert method, not the unsetChild method.  The question to ask is: is it the right choice to use the block name as the value of the _sortedChildren array ? Why not the block itself, just like the _children array ?

Comment: And why not the current block alias as the value of the _sortedChildren array, just like the key of _children ?.  Then, the code of unsetChild would be left invariant.  On the other hand, the code of a sorted getChildHtml('') should use the _children array to grab the block.

Comment: ... and the core/text_list _toHtml() method should also be updated to use the _children array to grab the block instance

Comment: and wowww... the <block ... after/before="name" /> should also adapted, aliases replacing names in the syntax...

Answer (score 3):

`unsetChild` is created for moving existing blocks from one place to another. You can unset block from it's default position, and insert block with the same name in some other place (you can't do this using `remove` method, because it will remove the block completely).

Comment: Thank you ! From what I read in the code, if the alias is unequal to the name, the block is not unset from _sortedChildren.  So, if you reinsert it with the same name, couldn't the same block occur twice in the _sortedChildren array ?

Comment: Yes, I think block will appear twice there.

Comment: Is this the intended behavior ? getChildHtml('') walks through _sortedChildren, and renders the blocks... Thus, if alias and block are unequal, but alias stays the same when you reinsert, I think the block will be rendered twice: not a move, but a copy of the block...

Comment: Now, if alias and name were equal and stay the same, the block is moved, because _sortedChildren[$name=$alias] was unset by unsetChild.  Hmmmm....

Comment: Erratum: please read "Thus, if alias and name are unequal," instead of "Thus, if alias and block are unequal,"

Comment: Finally the solution seems to be:

Comment: a) to drop a child having $name as its name and $alias as its alias: always issue unsetChild($name) followed by unsetChild($alias)

Comment: b) to move a child (using similar conventions): issue unsetChild($name) followed by unsetChild($alias) followed by insert($newChildAlias,$siblingName...)

Comment: Erratum: b) to move a child (using similar conventions): issue unsetChild($name) followed by unsetChild($alias) followed by 
insert($name,$siblingName,$after,$newChildAlias)

Comment: In blocks language, b) should be like this: <reference name="parentName"><action method="unsetChild"><alias>name</alias></action><action method="unsetChild"><alias>alias</alias></action><action method="insert"><name>name</name><siblingName>siblingName</siblingName><after>0|1</after><alias>newChildAlias</alias></action></reference>